# How to click on any web element if it is within span class and a tag

Tags: java

I have a website and it has a download button but there is no id it is in a span class download-data-link  I need to click on that download file in csv format

website is https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_index_data.htm

please help 
I have used  this code

```
element = driver.findElement(By.className("download-data-link"));
            element.click();
```

It didnt worked

Comment: Use python for this use case, it will be handy and you can get it. I see it is NSE website, I think you won't be able to query much, they will block your IP address. Downloading stock data and processing on them is a very common thing which person does :) use sharekhan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work ....

As the element is a href and it is a span class and within a a tag then you shoud use javascript executor...

use this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='download-data-link']//a")));
```

It should work..

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a CSS selector to capture the relationship from the `<span>` with the `.download-data-link` class, as a parent of the `<a>` tag?

```
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".download-data-link a"));
element.click();
```

Comment: it did not worked sir ... it gave me the same error as my code ... error:other element would receive click at point (some point , some point)

Comment: You should probably share your error message with your questions.

Comment: sorry my fault ... but i got what i needed ... sorry again